# React Native: Write value to variable outside of a inner function

Tags: javascript, android, json, react-native, fetch

i just startet with react native and currently working on a couchdb api for our project. I am doing my rest requests with fecht. But within the inner function i cannot write my responsetext (json) to variable i want to return.

```
_getDocument(pID)
{
    var result = "getDocument failed"

    var document = "https://"
        + this.connection.user + ":"
        + this.connection.password + "@"
        + this.connection.server + "/"
        + this.connection.database + "/"
        + pID;

    fetch(document)
        .then((response) => response.text())
        .then((responseText) => {

            result = responseText;
            Alert.alert('Fetch', result , [{text: 'ok'}])

        }).catch((error) => {
        console.warn(error);
    });

    Alert.alert('_getDocument', result , [{text: 'ok'}])

    return result;
}
```

at the end of my function the variable result still has the value "getDocument failed" and not my json string.
i already tried to store my response text somewhere else by calling another function but that didn't work as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn about **async vs sync** - in your code above you're running a series of synchronous statements - both assignments of the variables `result` and `document`, then running an asynchronous statement: `fetch`, then running two more sync statements using `Alert` and `return`.

We call the `fetch()` method asynchronous because it runs in the background and won't interrupt the code execution, by using the two `then()` statements you're utilising [JS promises](https://davidwalsh.name/promises) in which the functions you're passing (both `response.text()` and the second callback), will be executed when the fetch request finishes processing. This makes sense for an API call, as it could take some time.

You just need to re-think the structure of your code, possibly using a callback within the promise resolution function:

```
 _getDocument(pID) {
    // Variable declarations...

    fetch(document)
        .then((response) => response.text())
        .then((responseText) => {

        result = responseText;
        Alert.alert('Fetch', result , [{text: 'ok'}])

        this.fetchCompleted(result)

    }).catch((error) => {
        console.warn(error);
    });
}

fetchCompleted (result) {
    Alert.alert('_getDocument', result , [{text: 'ok'}])
    // Do something with result
}
```

Or, if you're executing this within a Component, you could simply set the state instead of running the callback:

```
this.setState({
    data: result
})
```

Comment: Instead of running the next method inside method you better should set the state after getting json responses. so that you might feel less coupled of the code.     this.setState({
    data: result
})

Comment: but fetchCompleted shouldn't be accessed because are inside inner object and it can't find funcion

Comment: Then add a reference to it: `const callback = this.fetchCompleted` and make use of that.